# SSIS Script Task Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to get this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302274/ssis-looping-through-servers-and-handling-failed-logins) working in my package, but I get the below error message on the first line.

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

I also get a warning saying "ex" is declared but never used.

Anyone know what I can do to fix this?

```
        string connString = Dts.Variables["User::SQLServer"].Value;

        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connString;
                connection.Open();
            }
            Dts.Variables["User::DatabaseCanConnect"].Value = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dts.Variables["User::DatabaseCanConnect"].Value = false;
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: string ex - You need to declare ex as a variable also

Answer (score 0):

```
string connString = Dts.Variables["User::SQLServer"].Value.ToString().Trim();
```

was what I needed.